# mailto trademark encoding

Tags: html, encoding, mailto

I'm trying to setup a mailto link with a trademark symbol inside the body text, something like this:

```
mailto:?body=Starttext PRODUCT <sup>tm</sup> - Award  Logo %0A%0A link%26type=2%26productName=bla%0A%0AEnd
```

My problem is now, that the `tm` is not well formed in some email clients. My question is, how can I encode this like the `&` → `%26`, or where is the TM well formed?

In my mail client, Outlook, it looks fine, but in the customer's client, it looks like crap.

Any suggestions?

I'm not sure if it's possible to fill in an encoded `tm` in a mailto link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
link.href = "mailto:?body=" + encodeURIComponent("Starttext PRODUCT ™ - Award Logo");
```

Note that some important details are missing:

- code
- What is the physical encoding of your source files
- What is the http charset header sent from your server

Comment: hey,
the physical encoding of my files is utf-8 and the charset header is this: text/html;charset=UTF-8
the problem with more code is, that i have to use/set this mailto URL in XSL Templates, JS and normal HTML.
thanks for your reply, so far.

Comment: @FrederikEmer in `XSL` you can use the `url:encode` function: `<xsl:value-of select="url:encode('Starttext PRODUCT ™ - Award Logo')" />`

Comment: thanks for the tips, the problem is my Product got a space between the tm and another name, so i've got a + encoded for the space in my output. i can try to encode that with url:encode and cut the + out of the string, save that to an xsl variable. maybe a workaround for that prob. My Problem is, that i can't do that encoding on Java, cause i need the data in other cases. best fred

Answer (score -1):

URL Encoding for TM is `%99`

Here's a great resource for future reference:

[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: `%99` didn't work with Outlook.  [Don't rely on information from W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/), [this is a case where they're wrong](http://w3fools.com/#html_urlencode).

Comment: @josh3736 It physically hurts just how wrong the information on w3schools is. For starters, [`ISO-8859-1` cannot even encode `™`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1)

Comment: thanks for the comments, my customer uses outlook too and he got the TM bug, but on my outlook it looks fine without any encoding.